# Flutter xcode build failed resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed.. Every time

Tags: ios, flutter

Every day, when I try to run my flutter project on my ios simulator, I get this error

[image]

If I run these two commands, it runs just fine

xattr -lr -Path To Project-

xattr -cr -Path To Project-

But needing to do this over and over is

1. annoying
2. hints at a larger problem.

Is there something I can do that will make it so I don't need to continually run these commands?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: nope, still have to use the two xattr commands every time I get the error

Comment: I have found my solution, but its a very specific case. I have a seperate "plugin" located outside the flutter app root folder with a path dependency called assets. I had to run xattr -cr <Path to ../../assets> in this folder. Do you have any dependencies that use png / jpg etc ?

Comment: I do not, I need to run these commands in every flutter project I create, so it doesn't appear to be specific to a particular project.